# How can I make sense of this Matrix inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, stochastic-matrices

In https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-02926037/document one page 35 the following Lemma is stated:

> **Lemma I.5:** Let $M \in (\Bbb R^+)^{N \times N}$ be a stochastic matrix. Then for any positive vector $x\in (\Bbb R_*^+)^N,$ one has
> $$
> \frac 1{Mx} \leq M \frac 1x
> $$

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S8aP.png)

where the division is to be interpreted component wise. How can I make sense or even proof this inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning seems to be pretty clear: $1\leq \left(\sum_j M_{i,j}x_j\right)\left(\sum_j M_{i,j}/x_j\right)$ for every $i=1,\dots,N$.

This follows from Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
1 = \sum_{j=1}^N M_{i,j}
= \sum_{j=1}^N \sqrt{x_j} \frac1{\sqrt{x_j}} M_{i,j}
\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^N x_j M_{i,j}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^N \frac1{x_j} M_{i,j}\right)^{1/2} .
$$

Comment: Thank you - I did understand the meaning of it, but don't know how I can apply Cauchy Schwarz there?

Comment: Ok. Also, I had a typo before (a $-1$ exponent that shouldn't have been there).